# Xamarin C# activity on screen (un)lock event

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android

Just wondering if there is an event In Xamarin for the activity class like `OnStart`, `OnResume`, `OnPause` etc. that gets fired when the user locks or unlocks their screen while the app is open, I've been looking for such an event in documentation etc, but I haven't been able to find it.

If there is no such event, then how can we create it?

Comment: Are you specifically talking about the Android Acitivities? Or Xamarin.Forms pages?

Comment: I am not using Xamarin Forms, I am talking about the Android Activities yes, so the C# code behind a page

Comment: So you want to know when your app is locked and unlocked right? Like an event?

Comment: @G.hakim that is basically what I am looking for yeah,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Xamarin C# activity on screen (un)lock event

you could create a listener class to listen for android lock screen and unlock events，use broadcast to receive the state of screen.

first create a **ScreenListener.cs** :

```
public class ScreenListener
{
    private Context mContext;
    private ScreenBroadcastReceiver mScreenReceiver;
    private static ScreenStateListener mScreenStateListener;

    public ScreenListener(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mScreenReceiver = new ScreenBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    /**
     * screen BroadcastReceiver
     */
    private class ScreenBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
    private String action = null;

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            action = intent.Action;
            if (Intent.ActionScreenOn == action)
            { // screen on
                mScreenStateListener.onScreenOn();
            }
            else if (Intent.ActionScreenOff == action)
            { // screen off
                mScreenStateListener.onScreenOff();
            }
            else if (Intent.ActionUserPresent == action)
            { // unlock
                mScreenStateListener.onUserPresent();
            }
        }
    }

/**
 * begin to listen screen state
 *
 * @param listener
 */
public void begin(ScreenStateListener listener)
{
    mScreenStateListener = listener;
    registerListener();
    getScreenState();
}

/**
 * get screen state
 */
private void getScreenState()
{
    PowerManager manager = (PowerManager)mContext
            .GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
    if (manager.IsScreenOn)
    {
        if (mScreenStateListener != null)
        {
            mScreenStateListener.onScreenOn();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (mScreenStateListener != null)
        {
            mScreenStateListener.onScreenOff();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * stop listen screen state
 */
public void unregisterListener()
{
    mContext.UnregisterReceiver(mScreenReceiver);
}

/**
 * regist screen state broadcast
 */
private void registerListener()
{
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.AddAction(Intent.ActionScreenOn);
    filter.AddAction(Intent.ActionScreenOff);
    filter.AddAction(Intent.ActionUserPresent);
    mContext.RegisterReceiver(mScreenReceiver, filter);
}

public interface ScreenStateListener
{// Returns screen status information to the caller
    void onScreenOn();

    void onScreenOff();

    void onUserPresent();
}
}
```

then in the **MainActivity.cs**:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity,ScreenStateListener
{
   ScreenListener mScreenListener;
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        mScreenListener = new ScreenListener(this);
    }
   protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        mScreenListener.unregisterListener();
    }

   protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        mScreenListener.begin(this);

    }
   public void onScreenOn()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("onScreenOn");
    }

   public void onScreenOff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("onScreenOff");
    }

   public void onUserPresent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("onUserPresent");
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/ActivityLifecycle) of Xamarin.Android activities lifecycle.

You can override any of the lifecycle methods like this:

```
protected override void OnResume() {
    base.OnResume(); 
}
```

Like in native Android `OnPause` is fired when the system is about to put the activity into the background. `OnResume` is called when the activity is ready to start interacting with the user.

`OnPause` and `OnResume` can be used for your (un)lock events.

Comment: yes, that is what I assumed, but my debugger is not triggering these overridden events when I turned of my display/locked my screen. However they do trigger when switching apps or pressing the home button, but not when locking my device.